# Disabling the SelectionChanged event of WPF combobox on navigating through arrow up and down key

Tags: wpf

Disabling the SelectionChanged event of WPF combobox on navigating through arrow up and down key.

I think it is repetitive questions but even am asking same question. Because i didn't get answer from whatever post already posted.

I wanted to disable SelectionChanged event on arrows up and down key.
I have two events PreviewKeyDown and PreviewKeyUp for combobox in which i have wrote "e.handled = true". This code is worked for all others key but not for up and down arrow key.
After pressing the arrow key's SelectionChanged event get triggered.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the following code and its work fine.

```
protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
            {
                if (IsReadOnly)
                {
                    if (e.Key == Key.Down || e.Key == Key.Up)
                    {
                        e.Handled = true;
                        return;
                    }
                }

                base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);
            }
```